# google places api requests - OVER_QUERY_LIMIT before actually over the limit

Tags: google-places-api

I have developed a google places application to get info about places.  I have verified my identity with google and as per the limits, I should be allowed up to 100 000 requests per day.  However, after under 300 requests (different numbers go through each day), I get the message back: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.  Any similar experiences or ideas how to enable the requests to go through?

Thank you.
D Lax

Comment: Please provide some code to support your question.

Comment: Places API allows only 1,000 request/Day.

Answer (score 0):

You can track your requests at

https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect#:stats

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. I was able to find 3 throttle limits for the places api, given by google.

1. 10 api calls per every 1 second
2. 100 api calls per every 100 seconds
3. 50,000 api calls per 1 day

If I were to go over any of these limits, I would receive the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error and it would return no results for that given address.

I found a way to have my program sleep for 11 seconds after calling the places api with a dataset of 10 addresses. Then the program would call the places api with a new dataset of 10 address. This solution gets around the 10calls/second and the 100calls/100seconds throttle limits. However, I did run into the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error once I tried my 25th dataset of 10 address (after 240 api calls). So it is clear that there are other throttles not published to help protect the google maps platform.

But, I did see that the limits mentioned above may be changed if you get in contact with the google api help team and sort it out with them.